# Autofill TextBox/Checkbox from a previous TextBox' value (VB.NET Database)

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

*Note: I'm using Visual Studio, original work was on SQL Server, moved to VB.NET*

I have a Textbox "ViewStatusTxt", next to it there's a Button "ViewStatusBtn"
Below it there's a TextBox "ViewNAMETxt", another TextBox "ViewACTIVITYTxt" and then a Checkbox "ModifyStatusCB"

I'm trying to auto-fill the Checkbox AND the Textbox based on the ID input there, however I really have no clue about it since I'm new to VB.NET

Here's the code used

```
Private Sub IDSearch(StatusViewBtn As String)
    ' ADD SEARCH QUERY PARAMETERS - WITH WILDCARDS
    SQL.AddParam("@StatusViewBtn", StatusViewBtn)

    'RUN QUERY - SEARCH GIVES THOSE RESULTS
    SQL.ExecQuery(" SELECT
                        aID,
                        Name,
                        Status,
                        Activity

                    FROM
                        [dbo].[initialTable]

                    WHERE
                        aID = @StatusViewBtn

                    ORDER BY
                        aID ASC")
End Sub
```

That's the function's code, which is fully working since it's a smaller version of the same one I used in a Search Page

Here's the button's function, which I'm sure is where I'm having problems, unless I need to add a specific function to the ViewNAMETxt

```
Private Sub StatusViewBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StatusViewBtn.Click
    IDSearch(StatusViewBtn.Text)
    ViewNAMETxt.Text = SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT
                                            Name
                                        FROM
                                            initialTable
                                        WHERE
                                            aID = @StatusViewBtn")
End Sub
```

And I haven't even started on the Checkbox, viewing how the first one caused me issues. Hopefully the solution would be similar to both of them.
Thanks for reading guys, and sorry for the newbie question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Suppose you have a table named YourTable(int KeyColumn, string StringColumn,  boolean BooleanColumn)

2- Create a form and put 2 textboxes and a checkbox and a button on it. KeyColumnTextBox, StringColumnTextBox, BooelanColumnCheckBox, SearchButton

3- In click event handler for SearchButton put the codes:

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click
    Dim connection = New SqlConnection("Your Connection string here")
    Dim command = New SqlCommand("SELECT StringColumn, BooleanColumn FROM YourTable WHERE KeyColumn=@KeyColumn", connection)
    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@KeyColumn", Int32.Parse(KeyColumnTextBox.Text)))
    connection.Open()
    Dim reader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        StringColumnTextBox.Text = reader.GetString(0)
        BooleanColumnCheckBox.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(1)
    End While
End Sub
```

Don't forget to `Imports System.Data.SqlClient` at top of your file.

Comment: I'm sorry but this really makes no sense; I've tried it, fixed all of the details missing from it, and it still makes no sense and gives off plenty of errors. I'm sorry, can you please be a bit more clear with the answer?

Comment: @The Edit; I know. I added this too. 
The error I'm getting now is
    "Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in System.Data.dll

    Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.String'."
At line 8 of the code you gave